# Spring Data - Repository bean ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I cannot understand how to explicitly assign an ID to a repository bean in Spring Data.

To be clear, suppose I defined the following interface in package `com.acme.repositories`

```
public interface MyJpaRepo extends JpaRespository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

As per documentation I can activate Spring Data JPA repositories simply by adding

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

Last, suppose that I have another bean in the same context which constructor **requires** a `JpaRepository` to be passed in. I would define it like that

```
<bean class="x.y.z.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg name="repository" ref="XXX" />
</bean>
```

Now, what should I use in place of `XXX`? Or, even better, how can I explicitly assign an ID to the `MyJpaRepo` repository beans?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of XXX use `myJpaRepo`.

source: [Spring Data Jpa document reference for repository id](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring)

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean class="x.y.z.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg name="repository" ref="<with qualified path>MyJpaRepo " />
</bean>
```